# Equivalent of str.lstrip(char) in jython < 2.1

Tags: python, jython

Consider the below piece of code:

```
word='hello.world'
//matchedWord to contain everything right of "hello"
matchedWord=word.lstrip('hello') //now matchedWord='.world'
```

How to achieve the same in jython 2.1 where str.lstrip(char) is not available. Any other work arounds to strip all the characters left of a word?

Comment: Note that stripping `hello` from a word means you want to strip the characters `h`, `e`, `l` and `o` from that word, regardless of ordering! You are looking for `if word.startswith('hello'): word = word[len('hello'):]` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to use `.lstrip()` you can reimplement that as a function:

```
def lstrip(value, chars=None):
    if chars is None:
        chars=' \t\n'
    while value and value[0] in chars:
        value = value[1:]
    return value
```

But you need to be aware of what `.lstrip()` (and `.rstrip()` and `.strip()`) strip a *set* of characters from the front, not a prefix. From the (cpython) documentation:

> Return a copy of the string with leading characters removed. The `chars`
>   argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed.
>   If omitted or `None`, the `chars` argument defaults to removing
>   whitespace. The chars argument is not a prefix; rather, all
>   combinations of its values are stripped:
>
> ```
> >>> '   spacious   '.lstrip()
> 'spacious   '
> >>> 'www.example.com'.lstrip('cmowz.')
> 'example.com'
> ```